# How to do memory management, monitoring, and testing in R?

Tags: r

I notice that using R to program constantly causing some running speed problem, especially when the code involves growing a list. It's just very unintuitive what is slowing down the program so dramatically during the looping.

Specifically I'm using caret to train a gbm model, after getting the tuned hyperparameter, I need to do LOOCV to obtain the test error, which demands me to train the model for n times (n=number of samples). All I store in the list is my prediction result. Yet the list grows slower as the loop progress.

Can you offer some general advice for testing the memory issues related to R programming?

Answer (score 0):

First create an empty list/vector. Size of your "n" so R has not to rewrite it every time it wants to add one additional value